# System.DateTime couses error while migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got the following class in my models

```
        public DateTime DateTimePosted { get; set; }
```

and it's causing this error while DB migrations 
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DateTimePosted"

but when I allow nulls in my model this way

```
        public DateTime? DateTimePosted { get; set; }
```

then migration is succesfull , but column in Db stays nullable,
but when I'm trying to pass it to Db by Seed method it works fine.

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult AddApartment()
    {
        return View(new Apartment { DateTimePosted = DateTime.Now });
    }
```

My question is
How to pass to DB date and time of posted data

Comment: Is DateTimePosted a new column that you are adding to an existing table into your database ?

Comment: yes it is a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error  because you are trying to add new non-nullable column on a table that already contains some data. Because you're adding a non-nullable column, DB Migrations doesn't know which value to set for the new column to thos already inserted lines into your table. To fix that you have two solutions:

- Making DateTimePosted a nullable data by using `DateTime?`
- Modify your newly generated migration file by locating the line that add your new column and add set the `defaultValueSql` parameter like below :

The code:

```
AddColumn("YOUR_TABLE_NAME", "DateTimePosted", 
   c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()")
);
```

Comment: data in Db is right now only for development tests, it would be easier to delete data or if necessary create new DB  ? it will  work fine then ?

Comment: I've deleted all db data , and right now i got this error :The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: You must give us the line at which the error occurs? I also think that this is another issue that is nt related to the first issue which is now fixed. What type did you set for this property in your EF configuration ?

Comment: visual studio stops on db.Savechanges ,right now property is'nt nullable and it  looks like :    public DateTime DateTimePosted { get; set; }